# Running FaceNet and MTCNN model simutaneously on 2 cameras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, face-detection, face-recognition

I am trying to run the MTCNN and FaceNet model on 2 cameras simultaneously. So, I am not getting any error while doing this but the code doesn't give me any results.

It just loads both the models and doesn't give me any predictions. Can anyone help me with this?

I have created 2 separate graphs and sessions using g=tf.Graph for MTCNN and FaceNet.

I think this error is coming due to multi-processing with TensorFlow as it might try to load MTCNN input to the Facenet graph. *this is my assumption.

Please let me know if you have any ideas about this. Thanks.

FaceNet:

```
with face_rec_graph.graph.as_default():
        self.sess = tf.Session()
        with self.sess.as_default():
            self.__load_model(model_path)
            self.x = tf.get_default_graph() \
                                        .get_tensor_by_name("input:0")
            self.embeddings = tf.get_default_graph() \
                                .get_tensor_by_name("embeddings:0")
            self.phase_train_placeholder = tf.get_default_graph() \
                                                 .get_tensor_by_name("phase_train:0")

            print("Model loaded")
```

face_rec_graph was created as follows:

```
class FaceRecGraph(object):
       def __init__(self):
            self.graph = tf.Graph();
```

MTCNN:

```
graph = tf.Graph()
    with graph.as_default():
        with open(model_path, 'rb') as f:
            graph_def = tf.GraphDef.FromString(f.read())
            tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
    self.graph = graph
    config = tf.ConfigProto(
        allow_soft_placement=True,
        intra_op_parallelism_threads=4,
        inter_op_parallelism_threads=4)
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    self.sess = tf.Session(graph=graph, config=config)
```

There is no error coming just both the cameras stop giving any result.